# Modifying value returned from a method in Scala (Highcharts lib)

Tags: scala, inheritance, highcharts, mocking, traits

I am using an external library in Scala, which uses a set of traits to pass around complex configuration options to different methods. This is Highcharts Scala API, but the problem seems to be more general.

The library defines a trait (HighchartsOptions in the actual usage), which is just a data transfer object that stores a number of fields and allows them to be passed around. Code simplified and generalized for clarity looks like this:

```
trait Opts {
    def option1: Int = 3
    def option2: String = "abc"
    //Many more follow, often of more complex types
}
```

As long as the complete set of options can be generated in one place, this allows for a neat syntax:

```
val opts = new Opts() {
    override val option1 = 5
    //And so on for more fields
}
doSomething(opts)
```

However, there are a few situations where one piece of code prepares such a configuration but another piece of code needs to adjust just one option extra. It would be nice to be able to pass some `Opts` instance to a method and let the method modify a value or two.

Since the original trait is based on `def`s rather than `var`s, it's easy to override an option's value only if the type of the object is known, like in the example above. **If a method receives only an instance of some anonymous subclass of `Opts`, how can it create another instance or modify the received one so that a call to e.g. `option2` could return a different value?** The desired operation is similar to what [Mockito's `spy`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy%28T%29) does, however I feel there should be some less contrived way than using a mocking framework to achieve this effect.

PS: Actually I am a bit surprised by the use of such an interface by the library's authors, so perhaps I'm missing something and there is some completely different way of achieving my goal of building a single set of options from several different places in the code (e.g. some builder object that is mutable and that I can pass around instead of the finished `HighchartsOptions`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest, simplest way.

Define a case class:

```
case class Options(
  option1: Int,
  option2: String
  /* ... */
) extends Opts
```

and implicit conversion from Opts to your Options

```
object OptsConverter {

  implicit def toOptions(opts: Opts) = Options(
    option1 = opts.option1,
    option2 = opts.option2
    /* ... */
  )
}
```

That way you get all copy methods (generated by compiler) for free.
You can use it like that:

```
import OptsConverter.toOptions

def usage(opts: Opts) = {
  val improvedOpts = opts.copy(option2 = "improved")
  /* ... */
}
```

Note, that Options extends Opts, so you can use it whenever Opts is required. You'll be able to call copy to obtain a modified instance of Opts in every place where you import the implicit conversion.

Comment: I think this solution is most elegant. The one with macros also looks quite tempting and requires even less code, but it depends on non-standard (at the moment) extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I would first check if using the Opts trait (solely) is an absolute necessity. Hopefully it's not and then you just extend the trait, overriding defs with vars, like you said.

When Opts is mandatory and you have its instance that you want to copy modifying some fields, here's what you could do:

Write a wrapper for Opts, which extends Opts, but delegates every call to the wrapped Opts excluding the fields that you want to modify. Set those fields to values you want.
Writing the wrapper for a broad-interface trait can be boring task, therefore you may consider using http://www.warski.org/blog/2013/09/automatic-generation-of-delegate-methods-with-macro-annotations/ to let macros generate most of it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to allow the trait to define it's own "copy" method, and allow it's subclasses (or even base class) to work with that. However, the parameters can really only match the base class unless you recast it later. Incidentally this doesn't work as "mixed in" so your root might as well be an abstract class, but it works the same way. The point of this is that the subclass type keeps getting passed along as it's copied.

(Sorry I typed this without a compiler so it may need some work)

```
    trait A {

    type myType<:A

    def option1: Int
    def option2: String

    def copyA(option1_:Int=option1, option2_String=option2):myType = new A {
      def option1 = option_1
      def option2 = option_2
    }

}

    trait B extends A { me=>
      type myType = B
      def option3: Double

    //callable from A but properly returns B

      override def copyA(option1_:Int=option1, option2_:String=option2):myType = new B {
          def option1 = option_1
          def option2 = option_2
          def option3 = me.option3            
        }   



//this is only callable if you've cast to type B 
           def copyB(option1_:Int=option1, option2_:String=option2, option3_:Double=option3):myType = new B {
              def option1 = option_1
              def option2 = option_2 
              def option3 = option_3         
            }


        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this solution requires the original trait to be modified, which I can't really do since the trait is part of the external library.

Comment: can't you just extend that trait, into an abstract class (A - above) and derive anything you're working with from A downward?

Comment: In theory yes, but it requires a change to all places where the trait is used in my code and it doesn't handle the case where I receive someone else's implementation which I can't modify.